# How do I access the returned value of a Java Request in JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, jms

I'm trying to create a simple test plan in JMeter to send data over JMS, using a Publisher and a Subscriber. I've got a Java Request which returns a SampleResult object containing a list of subresults, each containing a String ("Hello, world!" + count), and I want to be able to send these Strings over JMS, but I can't work out how to access them.

Everything is working fine in isolation, but how can I plug the result that my Java Request spits out into my Publisher so it can be sent?

Comment: Provide sample result and what you want to pass to Publisher.Use resular expression extractor to get data from Result and pass that variable reference wherever you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of your Java Request:

[image: Regular Expression Extractor configuration]

You can then use this in your JMS Sampler:

> ${data}